# PHP webpage not connecting to SQL server on other Device

Tags: php, sql, apache, mariadb

I have created a simple php program running on apache2 server, php does work, but it is not connecting to the sql server when I view the file on another device. The database I am using on my Debian 9 device is MariaDB.

```
<?php
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","login");
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'Martin';
$result = $conn->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $row['password'];
?>
```

I am prety sure I got the code right (i have tried mysql_connect and other methods).
I dont understand why the webpage is giving me an error when I try and view the page on another device.

The times it worked varied when I was using the Debian device. It would sometimes work, and sometimes not. The tables and database in the sql server is fine, I have checked it over, and I dont think it is a fault with that.

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from login.users;
+----+----------+----------+
| id | username | password |
+----+----------+----------+
|  1 | Martin   | pass     |
+----+----------+----------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Can someone help me? I think that I have to enable something in apache files but my knowledge is limited and I dont know what kind of problem I am getting.

Comment: Missing a double quote at the end of line 3?

Comment: _`the webpage is giving me an error`_ and the error is ?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from anything else, the following line:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'Martin';
```

should be

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = 'Martin'"; // add the missing double quote
```

If that doesn't resolve the issue, you should probably post the error message.

Comment: Yes, my bad, it does have a double quote in the code(copy paste error). When I view the script on a web browser it says that the server is 'unable to handle the request HTTP error 500'.

Comment: The browser message does not contain enough information to be useful. Look in your web server's log files to view the actual error generated by PHP.

Comment: [Sun Jun 03 18:12:24.097587 2018] [:error] [pid 30052] [client 192.168.0.9:44526] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in /var/www/html/db.php on line 8, referer: http://192.168.0.33/login.php [Sun Jun 03 18:12:24.097937 2018] [:error] [pid 30052] [client 192.168.0.9:44526] PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in /var/www/html/db.php on line 10, referer: http://192.168.0.33/login.php

Comment: [Sun Jun 03 18:12:24.100875 2018] [:error] [pid 30052] [client 192.168.0.9:44526] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_array() on null in /var/www/html/db.php:11\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/db.php on line 11, referer: http://192.168.0.33/login.php                                      _This is what is in the error log when running the login.php

Comment: Can you share the first dozen or so lines of db.php? Make sure to sanitize anything important (replace passwords / domains / db names).

Comment: In any case, based on your original post and that error, it is likely that this is the problem: 

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost","root","password","login");
```

You have the password wrong, or the username, or MySQL is not configured to listen to localhost, or the port is wrong, etc. Focus your efforts on simply connecting successfully to the DB. Try connecting with a desktop program like MySQL workbench or DBeaver and see where that gets you. You're never connecting to the database.

Comment: I have done some testing over the past few days, I created a new mysql user and that seems to work now. I have it running, but I am still confused why it didnt work. Thanks for trying to help me anyway.

Comment: The connection was not happening before. If you didn't change anything else besides creating a new user in the same MySQL DB, the problem may have been that your script is running on a different server, and MySQL was configured to not allow root to connect from remote hosts (a very sensible and common security precaution).